# SQL Reporting Services 2005 vs WPF Fixed Document Control

Tags: wpf

In my project i have used WPF and am following MVVM pattern.  So i have a report module in my project and the reports are just plain reports. So i would like to know  should i use SQL Reporting Service 2005 to create reports and then use report viewer as client or should i go for WPf Fixed Document Control- Document viewer.

Can anyone please tell me which of these will be easier to integrate with my project.

Please reply

Thanks 
Sharath

Answer (score 0):

### WPF Document (Fixed or Flow)

Pros:

- Easier to integrate. All is included in regular WPF
- Native
- More control on the output

Cons:

- Must program a lot for a multi-page report
- Must program a lot for headers, footes, groups, etc.

### SQL Reporting Services

Pros:

- Mature tools
- Interoperable with other solutions (IE asp.net)
- Groups, totals, page headers, graphics built in

Cons:

- Not native, must use a embedded windows form control
- Must deploy the reporting service runtime separately (not good for click-once apps)
- Hard to integrate to your business objects